# How to change an API request?

Tags: java, android

I'm new to android development. I have an example from github [here](https://github.com/rodion-m/DaDataExample). This example shows a way to interact with server to get suggestions on query.
Currently request body have following form:

```
{
  "query": "mosc",
  "count": 10
}
```

And i need to edit body like this:

```
{
  "query": "mosc",
  "from_bound": { "value": "region" },
  "to_bound": { "value": "region" },
  "count": 10
}
```

to make request show me only regions, not full address.

Piece of code, where request if forming:
DaDataRestClient.java

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setLogLevel(BuildConfig.DEBUG ? RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL : RestAdapter.LogLevel.NONE)
                .setEndpoint(BASE_URL)
                .setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {
                    @Override
                    public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
                        request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                        request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                        request.addHeader("Authorization", "Token ".concat(BuildConfig.DADATA_API_KEY));
                    }
                })
                .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
                .build();
apiService = restAdapter.create(DaDataService.class);
```

And ServerUtils.java:

```
if (queryRealmResults.size() == 0) {
                        RealmDaDataSuggestion suggestion = null;
                        try {
                            // Synchronously get the answer from DaData
                            suggestion = DaDataRestClient.getInstance().suggestSync(new DaDataBody(queryFromUser, 10));
                            ...
```

And DaDataBody class:

```
public class DaDataBody {
    private String query;
    private int count;

    public DaDataBody(String query, int count) {
        this.query = query;
        this.count = count;
    }

    public String getQuery() {
        return query;
    }

    public void setQuery(String query) {
        this.query = query;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }
}
```

I already spent a lot of time, but nothing works for me :(
Please help me, how can i edit this request? Thanks in advance!

P.S.: Eventually i want to create two EditText`s, one will be for region, second - for the city.

P.P.S.: Sorry for my English)

Comment: do you getting any error ? ad your api interface and enque method also

Comment: I don't have error in example. But I don't know how to add such expression ("from_bound": { "value": "region" }) in request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your model class like below

```
public class DaDataBody{

    @SerializedName("from_bound")
    private Property fromBound;

    @SerializedName("query")
    private String query;

    @SerializedName("count")
    private int count;

    @SerializedName("to_bound")
    private Property toBound;

    public void setFromBound(Property fromBound){
        this.fromBound = fromBound;
    }

    public Property getFromBound(){
        return fromBound;
    }

    public void setQuery(String query){
        this.query = query;
    }

    public String getQuery(){
        return query;
    }

    public void setCount(int count){
        this.count = count;
    }

    public int getCount(){
        return count;
    }

    public void setToBound(Property toBound){
        this.toBound = toBound;
    }

    public Property getToBound(){
        return toBound;
    }

    public class Property {

        @SerializedName("value")
        private String value;

        public void setValue(String value){
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String getValue(){
            return value;
        }


    }
}
```

Create request body for api call

```
        DaDataBody body=new DaDataBody();
        body.setQuery("your query");
        body.setCount(10);
        //set if you have value for tobound
        body.setToBound(new Property("your value"));

        //set if you have value for frombound
        body.setFromBound(new Property("your value"));
```

don't set value or set null for tobound and frombound if you don't have value. because gson don't include key and value for null valued keysin generate json.